# Symfony2 The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable" does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

It seems that path to annotations or namespaces are wrong but I can't figure out why. `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:mapping:info` outputs

```
[FAIL] AppBundle\Document\Test\Test
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable" in property AppBundle\Document\Test\Test::$createdAt does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Entity file:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document\Test;

use AppBundle\Document\Question\Question;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Document\Test\TestRepository")
 * @MongoDB\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $lastName;


    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @MongoDB\Timestamp()
     */
    protected $createdAt;
```

Stackoverflow already warn me that there are mostly code in my post but I think I have to show composer.json section:

```
"require": {
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.4",        
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.*",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
},
```

And yes I have `AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();` in autoload.php. I have looked at `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` and there things seems ok too:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
[...]
    'Gedmo\\' => array($vendorDir . '/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\MongoDB' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/mongodb/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib'),
    'Behat\\Transliterator' => array($vendorDir . '/behat/transliterator/src'),
);
```

Comment: Did you enable it in your config.yml?

Comment: I think so. 
`doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "mongodb://%mongodb_host%:%mongodb_port%"
            options: {}
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true`

Comment: i asked about `stof_doctrine_extensions` section (read NDM's answer please)

Comment: `stof_doctrine_extensions:
    mongodb:
       default:
           timestampable: true`

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html): you need to active the translatable in you `app/config.yml`:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    mongodb:
        default:
            translatable: true
```

and also add the translation entity mappings to doctrine:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Document
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Document"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_translator:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Document
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Document"
                alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
```

Comment: Author uses ODM, not ORM. But options should be similar

Comment: you are correct, I've changed to config to reflect mongoDB

Comment: Thank you for reply but no need for changes in `app/config.yml`. Now it works even without "AnnotationRegistry::registerFile" in autoload.php. Perhaps it was some cache/log issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find solution that worked. Have to manualy add annotation file to registry in autoload.php:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Mapping/Annotation/Timestampable.php');
```

Comment: The interesting part is that above change is needed only on first run after cache clearing with `php bin/console cache:clear`. Then it can be removed and everything works fine.

Comment: And on first run I also have to add `AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Configuration/Route.php');`. Otherwise routing not works.